# Database creation error: OperationalError() odoo error

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo

hello to all I am learning odoo and I do not understand why I have this problem already when I launch the server I have this error

```
    2022-08-30 13:54:22,175 10488 INFO ? odoo: Odoo version 15.0-20220816 
    2022-08-30 13:54:22,175 10488 INFO ? odoo: Using configuration file at C:\Users\pc\Desktop\odoo\server\odoo.conf 
    2022-08-30 13:54:22,175 10488 INFO ? odoo: addons paths: ['C:\\Users\\pc\\Desktop\\odoo\\server\\odoo\\addons', 'c:\\users\\pc\\appdata\\local\\openerp s.a\\odoo\\addons\\15.0', 'c:\\users\\pc\\desktop\\odoo\\server\\addons', 'c:\\users\\pc\\desktop\\odoo\\my_addons', 'c:\\users\\pc\\desktop\\odoo\\server\\odoo\\addons'] 
    2022-08-30 13:54:22,176 10488 INFO ? odoo: database: odoo15@localhost:5432 
    2022-08-30 13:54:22,308 10488 INFO ? odoo.addons.base.models.ir_actions_report: You need Wkhtmltopdf to print a pdf version of the reports. 
    2022-08-30 13:54:22,427 10488 INFO ? odoo.service.server: HTTP service (werkzeug) running on DESKTOP-EGBA0SF:8070 
    2022-08-30 13:54:22,457 10488 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: Connection to the database failed 
    Exception in thread odoo.service.cron.cron0:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\odoo\python\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "D:\odoo\python\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\odoo\server\odoo\service\server.py", line 473, in target
        self.cron_thread(i)
      File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\odoo\server\odoo\service\server.py", line 431, in cron_thread
        with conn.cursor() as cr:
      File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\odoo\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 709, in cursor
        return Cursor(self.__pool, self.dbname, self.dsn, serialized=serialized)
      File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\odoo\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 259, in __init__
        self._cnx = pool.borrow(dsn)
      File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\odoo\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 592, in _locked
        return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\odoo\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 660, in borrow
        **connection_info)
      File "D:\odoo\python\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 127, in connect
        conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
    psycopg2.OperationalError
    
    2022-08-30 13:54:22,491 10488 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: Connection to the database failed 
    Exception in thread odoo.service.cron.cron1:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\odoo\python\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
        self.run()
      File "D:\odoo\python\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
        self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\odoo\server\odoo\service\server.py", line 473, in target
        self.cron_thread(i)
      File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\odoo\server\odoo\service\server.py", line 431, in cron_thread
        with conn.cursor() as cr:
      File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\odoo\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 709, in cursor
        return Cursor(self.__pool, self.dbname, self.dsn, serialized=serialized)
      File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\odoo\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 259, in __init__
        self._cnx = pool.borrow(dsn)
      File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\odoo\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 592, in _locked
        return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\odoo\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 660, in borrow
        **connection_info)
      File "D:\odoo\python\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 127, in connect
        conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
    psycopg2.OperationalError
```

and when I try to create my database I have this error

```
    2022-08-30 13:58:42,045 10488 INFO ? odoo.http: HTTP Configuring static files 
    2022-08-30 13:58:42,091 10488 INFO ? odoo.sql_db: Connection to the database failed 
    2022-08-30 13:58:42,092 10488 INFO ? odoo.http: Generating nondb routing 
    2022-08-30 13:58:42,141 10488 INFO None odoo.service.db: Create database `TEST`. 
    2022-08-30 13:58:42,177 10488 INFO None odoo.sql_db: Connection to the database failed 
    2022-08-30 13:58:42,177 10488 ERROR None odoo.http:  
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\odoo\server\odoo\http.py", line 141, in dispatch_rpc
        result = dispatch(method, params)
      File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\odoo\server\odoo\service\db.py", line 462, in dispatch
        return g[exp_method_name](*params)
      File "", line 2, in exp_create_database
      File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\odoo\server\odoo\service\db.py", line 41, in if_db_mgt_enabled
        return method(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\odoo\server\odoo\service\db.py", line 130, in exp_create_database
        _create_empty_database(db_name)
      File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\odoo\server\odoo\service\db.py", line 99, in _create_empty_database
        with closing(db.cursor()) as cr:
      File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\odoo\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 709, in cursor
        return Cursor(self.__pool, self.dbname, self.dsn, serialized=serialized)
      File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\odoo\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 259, in __init__
        self._cnx = pool.borrow(dsn)
      File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\odoo\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 592, in _locked
        return fun(self, *args, **kwargs)
      File "C:\Users\pc\Desktop\odoo\server\odoo\sql_db.py", line 660, in borrow
        **connection_info)
      File "D:\odoo\python\lib\site-packages\psycopg2\__init__.py", line 127, in connect
        conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
    psycopg2.OperationalError
    2022-08-30 13:58:42,236 10488 INFO None odoo.sql_db: Connection to the database failed 
    2022-08-30 13:58:42,263 10488 INFO None werkzeug: 127.0.0.1 - - [30/Aug/2022 13:58:42] "POST /web/database/create HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0 0.000 0.211
```

this is my odoo.conf

```
    db_host = localhost
    db_maxconn = 64
    db_name = False
    db_password = 0000
    db_port = 5432
    db_sslmode = prefer
    db_template = template0
    db_user = odoo15
```

[image]
can some one help me please !

Comment: Connection to the database failed, pretty clear. Check your configuration, check if the database server is accepting your credentials (using psql or any other client), etc. etc.

Comment: yes i have already check my odoo.conf and this is the configuration for db db_host = localhost
db_maxconn = 64
db_name = False
db_password = *****
db_port = 5432
db_sslmode = prefer
db_template = template0
db_user = odoo15